# Can't access process.env values using dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I have a nextjs (not sure if it has any relevance or does it apply to nodejs as a whole) project in which I would like to access a value from `process.env` using a dynamic key:

```js
const myKey = 'MY_KEY'
console.log(process.env[myKey]) //undefined
```

For reference, I have tried:

```js
console.log(process.env['MY_KEY']) // gives value under MY_KEY
console.log(process.env.MY_KEY) // works too
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you share an executable snippet that showcases this behavior?

Comment: I am having this same issue.  `myKey` always returns undefined.

Comment: Seeing the same. Ended up conditionally assigning the value to a var, but really eager to understand how to solve this.

Comment: can you share simple project?

Comment: @JasperKennis Are you correctly [exposing the environment variables to the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) using the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix?

Comment: `let myEnv = { ...process.env }` and then `myEnv[myKey]` might work

Answer (score 31):

First of all, one thing to note, if you want to use `env` variables on the client then you [need to prefix](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser) them with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, or use the [older way](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) of exposing them to the client inside `next.config.js`.

As for the question, this is due to the nature of how Webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) works which I believe NextJs uses internally. It does direct text replacement at build time, in simpler words it just looks for `process.env.MY_KEY` string and replaces it with value. But if you destructure it then the plugin just can't find `process.env.MY_KEY` string anymore and you get nothing (`process.env` object is generated anyway, but it will be empty).

Although this is only true for client side code, because for server side Next actually uses a real `process.env` object and destructuring will work there.

For example, if we have `NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_KEY=somevalue` and we log this somewhere in the code:

```
  const key = 'NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_KEY';

  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_KEY);
  console.log(process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_KEY']);
  console.log(process.env[key]);
  console.log(process.env);
```

On client side you will get:

```
somevalue
somevalue
undefined
{} // empty object
```

And on server side you will get:

```
somevalue
somevalue
somevalue
{ ... } // object with all available env values, even system ones
```

There is a little bit of info about it in older [env docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables).

### Workaround

You could probably use [Runtime Configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration), but it has it's own limitations, for example, I think the page should be dynamic (should use `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`) to work.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    myEnv: 'somevalue',
    // or actually use process.env variables, they are all available here
    myEnv2: process.env.MY_ENV
  },
};
```

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const key = 'myEnv';

getConfig().publicRuntimeConfig[key] // 'somevalue'
```

Or just pass your variables through `getServerSideProps` like the other answer mentioned.

**EDIT:**
I've actually just tested `publicRuntimeConfig` and it works even on static pages, at least if you are using `next start`. Not sure why docs says that the page should have `getServerSideProps`. So this might be the solution in the end.

Answer (score 3):

As someone else has already correctly mentioned, this problem occurs because that's how the Webpack DefinePlugin works.

#### Solution

Extending the webpack config. You can filter out all environment variables, starting with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` and add them with the DefinePlugin webpack plugin to the `process.env` object. This way you can call them dynamically in the browser.

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { webpack, isServer }) => {
    const envs = {};
    
    Object.keys(process.env).forEach(env => {
      if (env.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC_')) {
        envs[env] = process.env[env];
      }
    })
    
    if (!isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify(envs),
      }))
    }

    return config
  },
}
```

your page

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const keys = ['FOO', 'NEXT_PUBLIC_FOO'];

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    keys.forEach(key => console.log(process.env[key]));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

#### Workaround

This workaround adds all environment variables prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC` to become dynamically available in the frontend.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const keys = ['FOO', 'NEXT_PUBLIC_FOO'];

export default function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    keys.forEach(key => console.log(props.envs[key]));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const envs = {};
  
  Object.keys(process.env).forEach(env => {
    if (env.startsWith('NEXT_PUBLIC_')) {
      envs[env] = process.env[env];
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      envs,
    },
  }
}
```

The important part is, that you use the `getStaticProps` method. Here you filter out all environment variables starting with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` and add them to the envs property. This allows them to be dynamically usable in the frontend.

In this example, the value of `NEXT_PUBLIC_FOO` will log to the console, while the value of `FOO` is `undefined`.

Comment: Your solution with custom `DefinePlugin` will actually break server side `process.env`. You need to check for `isServer` at the very least.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated my answer accordingly and fixed this bug

Comment: How can you loop through process.env? For me it shows an empty object, even though the keys (when accessed not dynamically) are available