# Pull from .env with a variable? ${} and [] not working

Tags: reactjs, variables, environment-variables

Can I use a variable in my process.env call?

I have the code

```
const optionsLang = `${lang}LANGOPTIONS`.replace("-","").toUpperCase();
```

and the .env file has

```
REACT_APP_ENUSLANGOPTIONS = {"title" : "applicationTitle", "buttonVerbiage":"Login Now"}
REACT_APP_ENCALANGOPTIONS = {"title" : "applicationTitle", "buttonVerbiage":"Login Now"}
REACT_APP_FRCALANGOPTIONS = {"title" : "applicationTitle", "buttonVerbiage":"Ouvir Une Session"}
REACT_APP_ESMXLANGOPTIONS = {"title" : "applicationTitle", "buttonVerbiage":"Iniciar Sesi%C3%B3n"}
and so on with various languages
```

so how can I do something like `process.env.${optionsLang}` (since that doesn't work)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, it doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean _"not working"_? Give a [mre].

Comment: This is for NextJS, and it appears that the OP is using CRA, but I believe this question is the more appropriate duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64152943/cant-access-process-env-values-using-dynamic-keys

Comment: Webpack will evaluate environment variables at build time, so dynamic access isn't possible directly. If you inspect the JS where you have something like `const myvar = process.env.TESTVAR`, you would actually see `const myvar = 'value of test var';.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your posts and help. We've decided to go a different route with this and will not be chasing this rabbit any longer.