# Typescript dotenv returning undefined when accessed by a variable

Tags: typescript, webpack, dotenv

I have set a helper to access my process.env as below:

```js
export const env = (key: string, def: any = null): string|any => {
    console.log(process.env["APP_ENV"], process.env[key], key === "APP_ENV")
    // @ts-ignore
    if ( process.env[key] instanceof String && process.env[key].length) {
        return process.env[key]
    }
    return def
}
```

This is injected to all my modules with plugins:

```json
plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        env: ['./plugins/config_helper', 'env'],
    })
]
```

when I access it as `env("APP_ENV")` I get a baffling result from my debug prints.

```
develop undefined true
```

Can someone explain this behavior? More specifically, why does process.env produce undefined when I access it via a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the why part of the question look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626413/1882663

Below is solution that I'm using in my app, note that I'm using prefix `REACT_APP_` for all my env variables.

webpack.config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const getReactEnvs = () => {
    const envs = {}
    
    Object.keys(process.env).forEach(env => {
        if(env.startsWith('REACT_APP_')) envs[env] = process.env[env]
    })

    return envs
}

module.exports = [
    new ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
    }),
    new DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': JSON.stringify({ ...getReactEnvs() }),
    }),
]
```