# Next.js: .env variable undefiend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I just migrated my app from React to Next.js but for some reason my environment variables are `undefined`, tho they worked fine in React. Can anyone assist me please?

_app.js

```
    const [apikey, setApikey] = useState(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(apikey)
    }, [])
```

.env

```
    REACT_APP_API_KEY=myapikey
```

Comment: try renaming `.env` to `.env.local` (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables)

Comment: For next, environment variables, that should be available in the browser package must be prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC`  (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73270626/how-to-get-next-js-environment-variables-on-client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a next app not a react app so the  env has to be named like below

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY
```

NEXT_PUBLIC is mandatory in a next env variable.